# Mootools Morph Height and back

Tags: height, mootools, toggle

Im looking for a solution for:
I want to toggel the height of a Div but not complet.
So i try this but didnt work. I see the first classchange in firebug and the heigth change to 36px.
But back didnt work. I try wiht add and remove class.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Zbbd9/1/**

```
$$('.outer').setStyle('height', '660px');

$$('.outer h2').addEvent('click', function(){
    if (this.hasClass('close')) {
        var parent = this.getParent();
        parent.removeClass('close');
        parent.morph({
        'height': '660px'
      });
    } else {
        var parent = this.getParent();
        parent.addClass('close');
        parent.morph({
        'height': '36px'
      });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zbbd9/2/

Got it.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting the wrong parent container.

Try it like this:

```
$$('.outer h2').addEvent('click', function(){
    var parent = this.getParent();
    if (parent.hasClass('close')) {
        parent.removeClass('close');
        parent.morph({
            'height': '660px'
        });
    } else {
        parent.addClass('close');
        parent.morph({
            'height': '36px'
        });
    }
});
```

Adding a class to identify the current state is a solid way to do it, but you might want to consider other alternatives, too, like using [toggleClass](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3atoggleClass) or referring to something completely different like a slider or similar.

Comment: yeah i made a break and then i found i out :D
But thx for your answer :) it works perfect.